# Rxjs with Axios Http Get, execute code after request finished

Tags: vue.js, rxjs, axios

I have a Vue application using TypeScript, Rxjs and Axios.

After making an http get request I want to execute some code, for example to hide a loading indicator.
What would the best way to do this be using Rxjs?
I know I'm subscribing to a stream of data here. Would a promise be better?

I currently have the below code...

```
Axios.get<Array<account>>(`https://localhost:5003/api/accounts`)
      .pipe(
        concatMap(response => response.data),
        filter(response => filerFunction(response))
      )
      .subscribe(
        response => {this.tableData.push(response); console.log('response: ' + response)},
        error => console.log(error)
      );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out. You could use the Finalize operator or the Complete function...

```
Axios.get<Array<account>>(`https://localhost:5003/api/accounts`)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(response => response.data),
    filter(response => filerFunction(response)),
    finalize(()=>{console.log("stop spinner in this function")})
  )
  .subscribe(
    response => this.tableData.push(response),
    error => console.log(error),
    () => console.log("or stop spinner in this function")
  );
```